# How do I skip certain Model Validations in Rails for speeding up Unit tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, email, rubygems

I have a validation for emails in my model using this gem https://github.com/validates-email-format-of/validates_email_format_of
How can I skip this validation check for Tests as this is causing a slow down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a conditional to the validation as the gem has that option.  So

```
validates_email_format_of :email, :message => 'is not looking good', unless: "Rails.env.test?"
```